# Extracting image caption and image url using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the image url and image caption from an article using BeautifulSoup. I can separate the article's image url and image caption from the preceding and following HTML but I can not figure out how to separate these two from their html tags . Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/dutch-philosopher-
koert-van-mensvoort-founder-of-the-next-nature-network-writes-a-
letter-to-humanity-619925063.html'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'image'})
```

The two sections I am trying to extract are the src= and the title= sections. Any ideas on how to accomplish these two parses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/dutch-philosopher-koert-van-mensvoort-founder-of-the-next-nature-network-writes-a-letter-to-humanity-619925063.html'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'image'})
print [i.find('img')['src'] for i in links]
print [i.find('img')['title'] for i in links]
```

Comment: the correct markup is `html5lib` not `lxml`, which is used ffor `xml`

Answer (score 4):

try the following to extract all the image tags

```
img = soup.findAll('img')
#depending on how many images are here you will probably need to loop through img
src = img.get('src')
title = img.get('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/dutch-philosopher-koert-van-mensvoort-founder-of-the-next-nature-network-writes-a-letter-to-humanity-619925063.html'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'image'})
if links:
    print(links[0].find('img')['src'])
    print(links[0].find('img')['title'])
```

---

Output:

> `http://mma.prnewswire.com/media/491859/Koert_van_Mensvoort.jpg?w=950`
>
> Dutch philosopher Koert van Mensvoort – founder of the Next Nature
> Network and Fellow of ‘Next Nature’ at the University of Technology in
> Eindhoven – has written a ‘Letter to Humanity’ in support of
> International Earth Day. (PRNewsfoto/Next Nature Network)

Answer (score -1):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526721/19773044)Thanks from @N cheadle

Try the following to extract all the image tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/dutch-philosopher-koert-van-mensvoort-founder-of-the-next-nature-network-writes-a-letter-to-humanity-619925063.html'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # or use BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
imgs = soup.findAll('img') # output: [ .... ]
#depending on how many images are here you will probably need to loop through img
for x in imgs:
  src = x.get('src') #output : 'test.cpm/images/1.png'
  title = x.get('title') #output : 'flover image'
```

Comment: This looks like a very near duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526743/12846804), except that findings keep being overwritten on top of each other inside the for loop. How do you propose to use what you got from, say, the first of `imgs`?